# Unique Android Device ID that can be acceptable by Play Store without Privacy Policy

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am new to Android Development so i do not have much knowledge about the Android Unique Ids and whether Play Store will accept my app or ask for me to include any PP. Purpose of using this is to identifier that which user is interested in the promotions that i will provide in my App (For this purpose I have my own view similar to Admob banner).
**Please let me know that how i can achieve this.**

Comment: privacy policies are not mandatory on play store

Answer (score 0):

I use [Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID)

> A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated when the user first sets up the device and should remain constant for the lifetime of the user's device. The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device.

```
android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(
            context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

It gets reset if user performs factory reset of device.

Comment: can i use it, when targeting 6.0 + ?